# Ruby implicit coercion on custom classes

Tags: ruby, class, coercion

I have my own class

```
class Mutnum
    attr_reader :value
    def initialize(number)
        raise TypeError, "Mutnum created on a non-numeric value" unless number.is_a? Numeric
        @value = number
    end
    def ==(other)
        if other.is_a? Mutnum
            other.value == @value
        else
            @value == other
        end
    end
    def set(newval)
        @value = newval
    end
    def to_i
        @value
    end
    def to_s
        @value.to_s
    end
    def +(other)
        if other.is_a? Numeric
            @value + other
        elsif other.is_a? Mutnum
            Mutnum.new(@value + other.value)
        end
    end
    def coerce(other)
        if other.is_a? Numeric
            [other, @value]
        else
            super
        end
    end
end
```

which functions essentially as a mutable number (as in, I can pass one to a function, change it in that function, and read the result from the location it was called). I'm using this to make using wxRuby and gosu in the same application less irritating.

I want to be able to say `Array#[Mutnum]` as in, `[1,2,3,4][Mutnum.new(3)]` should result in `4`.

What other functions should I add to Mutnum *edit* so that I can use Mutnums as array indices *\edit*? I suppose I can say `[1,2,3,4][Mutnum.new(3).to_i]`, but then I have to do more debugging.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your number. Just add things that you know you will use. If you need to add more later, than do so.

Comment: I want to know how I could edit Mutnum such that I can use them as array indicies.

Comment: Can you describe what it is that irritates you about wxRuby and gosu and how you are trying to fix it? There are probably other ways to explore. It looks like you might be wanting to keep some things(indices?) in sync but that is just a guess.

Comment: I was having a hard time getting both Wx::App#main_loop and GosuWindow#new to trigger at the same time, but I got something else working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as mutable numbers. But there are data structures that can *contain* a number. `MutableNumber` is not generally a good name for them. The way to use such container classes is:

```
class Container
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize value
    @value = value
  end
end

A, B = Container.new( 42 ), Container.new( 43 )
```

For what you want to do, you will have to say

```
[1, 2, 3, 4][ Container.new( 3 ).value ]
```

Get over it. It *is* possible to delegate many methods to `@value` assuming that this is of one of the `Numeric` subclasses. But with `Array#[]` method, it wont work, as its principles are different. The main point to get is, containers are actually *not* numbers.

You would have to define

```
class EasyArray < Array
  def [] arg
    index = arg.value rescue arg
    super index
  end
end

EasyArray[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ][ Container.new( 3 ) ] #=> 4
```

All in all, your best bet is not to define your own conntainer classes at all, but go with Petri nets from my `YNelson` gem; `gem install y_nelson`. After you install it, use Petri net places as containers:

```
require 'y_nelson' and include YNelson
P, Q = Place( m: 2 ), Place( m: 3 )
[ P, Q ].map &:value #=> 2, 3
```

Remember, when computer scientists want mutable numbers, they use Petri net places.

Comment: I know that the containers are not numbers, but I wanted to use them like they were. Can't I overwrite the [] function by doing `class Array; def [] arg; code here; end; end`?

Comment: You can, but nowadays, using subclassing, or using `using` is more in in Ruby.